# SQL count and combine

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm setting up a query to change the data of a form, count data and format it. At this moment I've got a table with vertical data. The data is shown in the image below. 
[image]

What I want to do is to create Group by on Number, after that count how many times a specific TypePak there is and split it to the right. As shown in the image on the right.

I've tried to do Pivot and it helped for a part of it, but that's not a good method. Then i've tried XML Path.

PIVOT

```
FROM            dbo.des_ombouw
GROUP BY Number, typePak) src
pivot 
(
    max(Expr1)
    for typePak in ([COLLI],[DOOS],[pallet],[Envelop])
) piv1
```

XML Path

```
  select distinct Number, abc = STUFF(( 
    select ',' + TypePak 
    from des_ombouw t1
    where t1.Number = t2.Number
    FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
from des_ombouw t2
```

In the image is what I want. There are more columns that has to be added, like weight of some package.
One of the problems too is that there are coming more columns, so this is not all!

Comment: That image is broken. However, instead of trying to reupload it, don't. If you're supplying data, it'll be far better received as tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statement.

Comment: @Larnu I have added the image inside the text.

Comment: *"However, instead of trying to reupload it, don't."*

Answer (score 0):

Two steps of aggregation with `row_number()` may do what you want:

```
select d.number,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then cnt end) as cnt_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then typepak end) as typepak_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then cnt end) as cnt_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then typepak end) as typepak_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then cnt end) as cnt_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then typepak end) as typepak_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then cnt end) as cnt_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then typepak end) as typepak_4
from (select d.number, d.typepak, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by d.number order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from dbo.des_ombouw d
     ) d
group by d.number
```